# Update document in cloud function from an Application

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to call a cloud function from my app to update some document, but something isn't working.

I don't think the problem is on my app code, probably is something in my node.js of cloud function.

Code from app

```
val functions = FirebaseFunctions.getInstance()
val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

val dataHashMap = hashMapOf(
    "db" to db
)
functions
    .getHttpsCallable("changeDocument")
    .call(dataHashMap)
    .continueWith {
        if(it.isSuccessful){
            Log.i("ChangeDocument", "Success")
        }else{
            Log.i("ChangeDocument", "Not success")
        }

    }.await()
```

Path doesn't matter because in my cloud function I'm hardcoding it.

Cloud Function in node.js

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

exports.changeDocument = functions
    .https.onCall(async(data, context) => {

        const db = data.db;

        const postCollectionRef = db.collection('usernames');
        const postDocumentRef = postCollectionRef.doc('8bahgPCa9sgcdmGkDkUQSwjT7F22');

        await postDocumentRef.update({ username: 'documentChanged' });
        return true;
    });
```

So it's not updating and I want cloud function to manage operations like changing a document.

Question: Am I doing something wrong? Should I check for something?

Comment: "but something isn't working" isn't enough information to work with.  Please edit the question to be clear about what specifically isn't working the way you expect, including any data you're working with, and logging or errors that indicate what's wrong.

Comment: Where you app is running? What the error that you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you very much for your help guys, after testing a lot of stuff with my node.js newbie code I made it work and understood what was wrong.

I started watching videos on cloud functions and noticed that they were using the firebase-admin import:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.changeDocument = functions
    .https.onCall(async(data, context) => {

        const postCollectionRef = admin.firestore().collection('usernames');
        const postDocumentRef = postCollectionRef.doc('8bahgPCa9sgcdmGkDkUQSwjT7F22');
        
        return await postDocumentRef.update({
            username: `documentChanged`
        });
    });
```

And now looks like it access correctly to the database and updates the document. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You can grant "**allUsers**" with "**Cloud Functions Invoker**" role in Cloud Function:

[image]

Comment: As @guillaumeblaquiere said, touching security wasn't what I was looking for, anyways thank you for showing this option that I didn't know!